# Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

This question has three parts.

a) Difference between continuity and uniform continuity

b) Geometrical meaning of uniform continuity

c) Correct the example

---

Definition of Continuity of a function in an interval $I$ is quite similar to uniform continuity.

I know that continuity is a pointwise property of a function and that when a function is continuous in an interval it means that it is continuous in every point in that interval. It is also easy to unterstant what this geometrically means (i think).

[image]

The first one is clearly a continuous function while the second one is not. The same logic applies to functions with more variables.

---

However i don't understand what uniform continuity means geometrically and how do we show in which interval  a function is uniformly continuous.

---

For Example: 
$$ f(x,y) = x^2 + xy $$

The definition of uniform continuity says:

We have two points $P=(x,y)$ and $P_0 = (x_0,y_o) $

$$ \forall ε>0 \exists d>0 / \forall P,P_0 \in I (|x-x_0|<δ, |y-y_0| < δ \Rightarrow |f(P) - f(P_0)|<ε )$$

So we take $ |x-x_0|<δ $ and $ |y-y_0|<δ $

$$|x^2 +xy -x_0^2 -x_0y_0|= | (x-x_0)^2 + (x-x_0)(y-y_0) + (2x_0 + y_0)(x-x_0) + x_0(y-y_0)|<δ^2+δ^2+|2x_0+y_0|δ + |x_0| δ = 2δ^2 + (|2x_0 +y_0|+|x_0|)δ<2δ^2+(3|x_0|+|y_0|)δ $$

Now if we choose $δ<1$

$$|f(P)-f(P_0)|< (3|x_0|+|y_0|+2)δ=ε \Rightarrow δ=\frac{ε}{3|x_0|+|y_0|+2} $$

Now is the condition for the function to be uniformly continuous, δ to be positive?

In this case 
$$ δ>0 \forall P_0 \in \mathbb R^2 $$
So the function is uniformly continuous in $ \mathbb R^2 $ .

However i previously chose $ δ <1 $ so $|PP_0|<1 $. Doesn't that affect the outcome?

Comment: The condition for uniform continuity is that you can choose $\delta$ in such a way that it doesn't depend on $P_0$ but rather only on $\varepsilon$. Your argument suggests but does not prove that you can't do this (and in fact you can't) on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can rigorously prove that your function is not uniformly continuous by selecting $\varepsilon=1$, letting $\delta>0$ be arbitrary and considering the point $P_0=(\frac{1}{\delta^2},0)$.

Comment: In the definition of continuity, "uniform" relates to the choice of $\delta$, given $\varepsilon$. If you can choose $\delta$ independent of the point $x$ where you prove continuity you have uniform continuity. A continuoud function on a  bounded closed interval is always uniformly continuous, so searching in this context will be in vain. Examples of not uniformly continous functions require either an open domain of defniitin or an unbounded one.

Comment: Look at p. 30 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/metricspaces.pdf, especially the graphs. In the definition given on that page you can take $X$ and $Y$ to be subsets of $\mathbf R$ and $d_X(x,y)$ to mean $|x-y|$ and similarly for $d_Y$. On p. 31 there are examples worth looking at too, including some uniformly continuous functions on unbounded intervals in $\mathbf R$ (on a closed bounded interval of $\mathbf R$ every continuous function *must* be uniformly continuous, but on other intervals they may or may not be uniformly continuous).

Comment: It does *not make sense* to ask if a formula like $x^2 + xy$ is uniformly continuous.  You *must* specify the domain of interest.  To give a one-variable example, the function $x^2$ viewed $\mathbf R \rightarrow \mathbf R$ is not uniformly continuous but the same function $x^2$ viewed $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbf R$ is uniformly continuous.  The examples in the link of my previous comment address this distinction for $x^2$.  In your case, $x^2 + xy$ is *not* uniformly continuous when it has domain all of $\mathbf R^2$, but it is uniformly continuous on every bounded region of $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: In a bounded region all points $(x,y)$ will satisfy $|x| \leq R$ and $|y| \leq R$ for some $R > 0$. Therefore in your calculations, if $|x - x_0| < \delta$ and $|y - y_0| < \delta$ *in that bounded region* then you essentially computed $|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < (4R+2)\delta$, so by using $\delta = \varepsilon/(4R+2)$ you'll have $|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon$ and thus you'd have proved $x^2 + xy$ is uniformly continuous *on that bounded region*.  Got it?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Things seem kind of clearer to me now. KCd nice reference!!! I'll look more into it and I'll get back to you if I have any problems.